# Wordpress - custom post type has been queried as attachment

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom CPT named `restaurant` and I need to create url in different languages using `WPML`, like:

```
http://example.com/restaurants/latvia/riga/restaurant-name
http://example.com/it/ristoranti/lettonia/riga/nome-ristorante
```

In the main language it works, no problem at all.
The problem is with the `it` lang, if I visit the link I get 404 page.
If I add `var_dump` to the `$query` in `pre_get_posts` I get:

```
object(WP_Query)[2049]
  public 'query' => 
    array (size=1)
      'attachment' => string 'steiku-haoss' (length=12)
  public 'query_vars' => 
    array (size=53)
      'attachment' => string 'steiku-haoss' (length=12)
      'error' => string '' (length=0)
      'm' => string '' (length=0)
      'p' => int 0
      'post_parent' => string '' (length=0)
      'subpost' => string '' (length=0)
      'subpost_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'attachment_id' => int 0
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'static' => string '' (length=0)
      'pagename' => string '' (length=0)
      'page_id' => int 0
      'second' => string '' (length=0)
      'minute' => string '' (length=0)
      'hour' => string '' (length=0)
      'day' => int 0
      'monthnum' => int 0
      'year' => int 0
      'w' => int 0
      'category_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'tag' => string '' (length=0)
      'cat' => string '' (length=0)
      'tag_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'author' => string '' (length=0)
      'author_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'feed' => string '' (length=0)
      'tb' => string '' (length=0)
      'paged' => int 0
      'meta_key' => string '' (length=0)
      'meta_value' => string '' (length=0)
      'preview' => string '' (length=0)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
      'sentence' => string '' (length=0)
      'title' => string '' (length=0)
      'fields' => string '' (length=0)
      'menu_order' => string '' (length=0)
      'embed' => string '' (length=0)
      'category__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'category__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'category__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_name__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag_slug__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag_slug__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_parent__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_parent__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'author__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'author__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'meta_query' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  public 'tax_query' => null
  public 'meta_query' => boolean false
  public 'date_query' => boolean false
  public 'post_count' => int 0
  public 'current_post' => int -1
  public 'in_the_loop' => boolean false
  public 'comment_count' => int 0
  public 'current_comment' => int -1
  public 'found_posts' => int 0
  public 'max_num_pages' => int 0
  public 'max_num_comment_pages' => int 0
  public 'is_single' => boolean true
  public 'is_preview' => boolean false
  public 'is_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_archive' => boolean false
  public 'is_date' => boolean false
  public 'is_year' => boolean false
  public 'is_month' => boolean false
  public 'is_day' => boolean false
  public 'is_time' => boolean false
  public 'is_author' => boolean false
  public 'is_category' => boolean false
  public 'is_tag' => boolean false
  public 'is_tax' => boolean false
  public 'is_search' => boolean false
  public 'is_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_comment_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_trackback' => boolean false
  public 'is_home' => boolean false
  public 'is_404' => boolean false
  public 'is_embed' => boolean false
  public 'is_paged' => boolean false
  public 'is_admin' => boolean false
  public 'is_attachment' => boolean true
  public 'is_singular' => boolean true
  public 'is_robots' => boolean false
  public 'is_posts_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_post_type_archive' => boolean false
  private 'query_vars_hash' => string '5215071224e026852fe2fe893457f985' (length=32)
  private 'query_vars_changed' => boolean false
  public 'thumbnails_cached' => boolean false
  private 'stopwords' => null
  private 'compat_fields' => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'query_vars_hash' (length=15)
  1 => string 'query_vars_changed' (length=18)
  private 'compat_methods' => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'init_query_flags' (length=16)
  1 => string 'parse_tax_query' (length=15)
```

As you can see it is queried like `attachment`.

I have also created a custom `rewrite_rule` but is ignored, I also tryed to hard-code the value but WP will ignore it anyway:

```
add_rewrite_rule($lang_code . '/' . $pt_translated . '/lettonia/riga/steiku-haoss/?$',
                    'index.php?&post_type=' . $pt_original . '&mlt_location=lettonia&name=$matches[3]', 'top');
```

This is my reg_exp: `it/ristoranti/.+?/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$`

How is this possibile?

**Edit**
I use WPML

Comment: How do you handle your website translation? With which plugin? Polylang? WPML?

Comment: I use WPML - will add to the question

Comment: Then you shouldn't have to do your own rewrite rule if WPML is correctly configured. Please check that the custom post type is set as translatable in WPML > Translation management > Configuration of multilingual content ; and that the CPT slug is translated through wpml string translation. And flush your permalinks by visiting the permalinks settings page.

Comment: The problem isn't that `restaurants` is not translated but is the `lettonia/riga/steiku-haoss` that in the italian section point to 404 page while in the english page works fine.
Looks like wp do not find the post. We tried to add `CPT permalinks plugin` and the problem is on `%category%/%postname%`

Comment: Does `riga` is supposed to be a parent page of `teiku-haoss`?

Comment: maybe `'rewrite' => array('slug' => $pt_translated, 'with_front' => true),` ?